# How to zoom on the center of an image?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to zoom on the center of an image.

I tried different things like `imageWrapper.width().left`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.process-diagram-zoom-in', function(){
    var div = $(this).parents('.container-fluid:first');
    var imageWrapper = div.find('.image-wrapper');
    imageWrapper.width(imageWrapper.width() * 5.1);
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on StackOverflow! When you ask a question, try to provide a bit more context — and you should give the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you already know how to magnify the image, so what you need to do is make sure it's centered inside a container.

This can be done with simple CSS.

For the container:

```css
position: relative;
```

And for the image:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, i need a javascript code that zooms in from the center

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context, explain what you want to do. Answering is hard when one has to guess the question ;)